# Spock's @IgnoreIf Closure doesn't see System prop variable, set in jUnit's Suite

Tags: automated-tests, spock, geb, test-suite, junit-runner

I Use Geb + Spock + jUnit runner + Maven
My Specs are like:

```
@Stepwise
class My_Spec extends GebReportingSpec {

    @IgnoreIf({properties['sss'].contains('true')})

    def "testFeature 1" (){
        println ("--> Feature 1 runs")
        given:
        println ("--> mySystemProp is: ${properties['sss']}")
        ...
        when:
        ...
        then:
        ...
    }

    def "testFeature 2" (){
        println ("--> Feature 2 runs")
        when:
        ...
        then:
        ...
    }
}
```

I need to run my Specs with jUnit runner because i need to group it in TestSuites. I Found a way to set System property before testSuite run. It available in jUnit 4.9 - @ClassRule. So, i use it here. 
By this way my TestSuites are like:

```
    @RunWith(Suite.class)
    @Suite.SuiteClasses([
            My_Spec.class,
            My_Spec1.class,
            My_Spec2.class
    ])
    class TestSuite extends Specification {
                @ClassRule
                public static ExternalResource testRule = new ExternalResource(){
                @Override
                        public void before() throws Throwable{
                                System.setProperty('sss', 'true')
                }
        }
}
```

But @IgnoreIf behaviur doesn't work: it doesn't see added system property 'sss' however, in feature method this property is available:
when feature runs, it gives next output:

```
Running TestSuite
--> Feature 1 runs
--> mySystemProp is: true
--> Feature 2 runs
```

All this i run with maven install. 
Piece of my pom.xml:

```
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <includes>
                <include>TestSuite.*</include>
            </includes>
            <systemPropertyVariables>
```

What am i doing wrong? 
If all is correct - How can i make it work with spock's @IgnoreIf and props, that i need to define in jUnit TestSuite?
( Please, do not offer to use jUnit's @Categories. )

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `properties['sss']` resolves to the right method call from within the closure passed to `@IgnoreIf`? I have been bitten by trying to be too groovy in the past, especially trying to use this kind of concise expressions with static imports when resolving system props in particular. Have you tried changing it to `System.getProperty("sss")`?

Also, the closure passed to `@IfIgnore` has a delegate set to `org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.PreconditionContext` which has `sys` property, so you could try `sys["sss"]` instead. If that doesn't help then you can debug the properties available in the closure by changing your code to:

```
@IgnoreIf({ println sys; sys["sss"].contains("true") })
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for reply.

Comment: 1.About 'too groovy' style: - i have tried `System.getProperty("sss")`, `System.sss`, `System.properties.get("sss")` - and still no success. So looks like this is not a problem. 2.About sys property debugging - there are a lot of System properties are being printed out - except 'sss'. So - the problem is: System property, that is created in @ClassRule, ExternalResource block - is not global. I don't know inner processes behavior of JVM enough to understand why it works this way ((

Comment: Have you tried [setting properties in your build](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html) instead of using a class rule? Or maybe using `@Rule` instead of `@TestRule`? Also, I'm not sure that you should use a custom test runner when running spock tests because there is a Spock specific one called [Sputnik](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/blob/master/spock-core/src/main/java/spock/lang/Specification.java#L34).

Comment: Have you considered using [SpockConfig.groovy](http://blog.proxerd.pl/article/segregating-spock-specifications-with-spockconfig-groovy-and-annotations) to achieve what you're after? Can you please explain what your exact use case is, that is why do you want to ignore certain specs based on system properties set in a rule applied to a test suite?

Comment: Look: i Have a registration process Testing Spec. It has a few features. Some features - are Regiatration process actions, but some features - are Checks (verifications, acceptances). I need to write Specs for already Registered users. So, in preconditions for such Spec - i need to register a new User. So - i can usemy previous Spec for this. But I don't need to make all Checks! So, if i could use `@IgnoreIf` - i would be ble to excluse all checks, marked them with `@IgnoreIf`. Mybe you can suggest me another solution?